# Latex box around set of equation

Tags: latex, border, formula, equation, box

I would like to display a formula in latex as the following. The space between the left border and the formula should be adjustable to 1cm.
[Boxed equation with 1cm space to left border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n02ju.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to draw frames around aligns is the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align,colback=white]
x &= x\\
&= x
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]